# Get various items from JSON

Tags: python, json

I have the following json from imdb

[Json](http://pasted.co/0a2fe87f)

code looks like this:

```
import json, requests 
url=('http://www.theimdbapi.org/api/find/movie?title=transformers&year=2007')
response = requests.get(url) 
dict_values = json.loads(response.text)
```

How do i extract different values from it (`['title']`,`["budget"]`,`["release_date"]`, etc...) (like filtering with grep)

```
>>> type(dict_values)
<type 'list'>
```

I do this:

```
>>> print(dict_values['title'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

I assume that the values ['title']["budget"]["release_date"] etc... are keys inside dictionary that are inside a list that is inside a dictionary, or something of sorts :) ... And I can't figure it out

Comment: 1. Requests deserialises JSON for you, use `response.json()`. 2. Given that you explicitly checked and found a list, *why did you try to index it with a string?!* JSON arrays become lists, which you index ordinally.

Comment: first, don't use the variable name `dict_values` for an object whose type is decidedly non-dict.  While I haven't used the API in question, I imagine if you iterate through the *list* of returned results, you'll find individual list elements that you can then retrieve the value of things like `title` for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the comments, you could iterate over the elements in the results list and get the parameters that you're looking for:

```
titles = [result["title"] for result in results]
```

and so on...